# Nancy/Owin can't browse to URL using DNS on the same server

Tags: owin, nancy

I have a Nancy rest api that is bound to http://*:12345 and uses windows auth.

When deployed it's being used by services on other servers fine using the DNS of the server (http://dns:12345/api/blah) but for some reason any service sitting on the same host cannot use this URL to access the API but must instead use http://localhost:12345/api/blah.

When I browse in IE on that server to http://dns:12345/api/blah I'm prompted with a credentials dialog. When I enter my credentials they always get rejected (despite having access, as proved by the fact that the same test from another server is fine).